# How to draw a slider button with a custom defined numeric value?

Tags: python, interface

The following code generates this UI:

```
    row = layout.row()
    row.prop(mesh, "use_auto_smooth", text="BreakEdge")
    row.active = mesh.use_auto_smooth and not mesh.has_custom_normals
    row.prop(mesh, "auto_smooth_angle", text="Angle")
```

[image]

This pretty much replicates the generic Blender Mesh Data panel.

What I would like to do is set the 180 by default to something like 30 which is more common for hard edge modeling than 180 to break an edge.

Would something like this even be possible overwriting the custom value I would like to begin with?

Comment: I think the _question title_ and the _content of the question_ are quite different. Maybe it doesn't seem this way from the point of asking, but from a practical standpoint drawing just _any_ slider which you can define yourself entirely using bpy.props vs setting the default of an existing mesh attribute are very different things.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is possible to set the default `auto_smooth_angle` of each new Mesh object -- I think your reason for trying is legitimate. If it isn't possible there's an alternative you might be interested in.

Rather than changing a default property of a mesh's *auto_smooth_angle* a solution could be to offer an *EnumProperty* with some quick-pick options, in addition to the existing slider. The enum would update the slider when an option is selected, if you want to fine tune then you use the slider.

[image]

here the rough code:

```
import bpy
import math
from math import radians

class LayoutDemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the scene context of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "Layout Demo"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layout"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene

        obj = context.active_object
        if obj and obj.data:
            mesh = obj.data
        else:
            return

        row = layout.row(align=True)
        row.prop(mesh, "use_auto_smooth", text="BreakEdge")
        row = layout.row(align=True)
        row.active = mesh.use_auto_smooth and not mesh.has_custom_normals
        row.prop(mesh, "claas_smooth_angle", expand=True)
        row.prop(mesh, "auto_smooth_angle", text="")


def register():

    def set_smooth_shade_angle(self, context):
        obj = context.active_object
        if obj and obj.data and obj.type=="MESH":
            mesh = obj.data
            mesh.auto_smooth_angle = radians(int(self.claas_smooth_angle))

    bpy.types.Mesh.claas_smooth_angle = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        items=[(str(j), str(j), "", i) for i, j in enumerate([30, 45, 90])],
        default="30",
        update=set_smooth_shade_angle)

    bpy.utils.register_class(LayoutDemoPanel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(LayoutDemoPanel)
    del bpy.types.Mesh.claas_smooth_angle


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

or

```
    row = layout.row(align=True)
    row.prop(mesh, "use_auto_smooth", text="BreakEdge")
    row = layout.row()
    row.active = mesh.use_auto_smooth and not mesh.has_custom_normals
    split = row.split(percentage=0.4)
    row = split.row()
    row.prop(mesh, "claas_smooth_angle", expand=True)
    split = split.split() 
    row = split.row()
    row.prop(mesh, "auto_smooth_angle", text="")
```

[image]

Comment: I tried it out but nothing really changes when I press the button. Only the slider really has an influence. But I learned today that you can call bpy commands and there I could add a standard value - have to look into this as well. Thank yoiu for everything!

Comment: it works here, maybe you copied it wrong. clicking the 30/45/90 enum, changes the auto_smooth_angle, and whenever it is changed (via code, or via ui) it sends its own update to change the way it gets displayed.

Comment: this won't affect the default of the auto_smooth_angle, incase that was perceived to be the case. This just provides an easy way to set that angle.

Comment: I must not have been clear in my English. What I mean no matter what button I press, the angle slider value is always valid.